# When is a quotient stack of finite type?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

Let $k$ be a field. Let $X$ be a scheme over $k.$ Let $G$ be an affine smooth group scheme over $k$ acting on $X.$ Suppose $X$ is of finite type over $k.$ Does this guarantee that the quotient stack $[X/G]$ is of finite type?

We know $[X/G]$ is locally of finite type over $k$. So the question is whether $[X/G]$ is quasi-compact.

Comment: Yes it is of finite type.

Comment: How does one prove it?

Comment: If X \to Y is a map of top spaces s.t. X qc, then so is f(X) (easy exercise). See also https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04YC